# How do I add a class to WTForm Radio field?

Tags: flask, uikit, jinja2, wtforms

I am attempting to style my WTForm Radio inputs with UIkit, but when looping through each field, I can't figure out how to get the class to apply. If I add the `form.difficulty(class_"uk-radio")` to the `for` loop, I get a crazy output instead of the formatted field. What is the proper syntax to apply this UIkit class to the radio field within a WTForm?

Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form class="uk-grid-small uk-background-muted uk-padding" action="/ask/" method="post" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-width-1-2@s uk-margin-small">{{ render_field(form.title,placeholder="The Problem", class_="uk-input") }}</div><br>

    <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-small">
        <strong>Question Difficulty:</strong>
        <br>
        {% for subfield in form.difficulty(class_="uk-radio") %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td>
                <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-small">
        {{ render_field(form.body,placeholder="My device probably has a virus. I clicked the wrong link, and I have like a million popups a minute now. Minute.tech HELP! I need some direction here guys.", class_="uk-textarea", rows="20", cols="100") }}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-small">{{ render_field(form.tags,placeholder="Mac, virus, Facebook, etc", class_="uk-input") }}</div>
    <br>
    <div class="uk-width-1-4@s uk-margin-small">
        <input class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit" value="Ask">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Python**

```
class AskForm(Form):
    difficulty = RadioField('Difficulty Rating', choices = [('1','1'), ('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5')])
    title = TextField('Title:', [validators.Length(min=5, max=100)])
    body = TextAreaField('Desciption:', [validators.Length(min=10, max=2000)])
    tags = TextField('Tags:', [validators.Optional()])
```

**Results:**

[image: Results from adding class to WTForm radio]

EDIT:
Tried `{{ render_field(form.difficulty, class_="uk-input") }}`, output still formatted vertically and not styled

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but here is how you do it:

```
 <div class="uk-input">
        
             {{form.difficulty.label}}
            
            {% for subfield in form.difficulty %}
    
                {{ subfield(class="class name") }}
                {{ subfield.label }}
   
            {% endfor %}  
    
    </div>
```

you could also do the same for label:

```
 {{ subfield.label(class="class name") }}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no subfields, `difficulty` is one field with multiple choices.
Render it like any other field and it should work.

```
{{ render_field(form.difficulty, class_="uk-input") }}
```

Comment: Tried this; the radio buttons are not styled, and display vertically instead of horizontally which I do not want (output updated in post)

Comment: It's a presentation issue. The form & field are working as intented.

Comment: Gotcha, so you are suggesting I can't add a class to the radio field of the WTForms? Maybe I will try and use the Flask `request` field in conjunction since I don't really need to verify a radio field input

Answer (score 1):

using this way i was able to achieve horizontal layout

```
<div class="uk-input">
    <table>
        <tr><td> {{form.difficulty.label}} </td></tr>
        <tr>
        {% for subfield in form.difficulty %}

            <td>{{ subfield }}
            {{ subfield.label }}</td>


        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      </table>
</div>
```